# Sum of numeric values in all events in given time period

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have following events that are logged periodically (every minute):

```
14:58 index=prod_service service.error error.count="3"
14:59 index=prod_service service.error error.count="4"
15:00 index=prod_service service.error error.count="0"
15:01 index=prod_service service.error error.count="10"
```

I've set up an alert to alert me when we have 10 Events in an hour that have more than "0" error.counts, however I would like to change it to alerting me when the count over all events is greater than 10 in an hour. So how can I sum the error.count over all events (which would be 17)

My current query only counts the number of events that have more than 0 errors...:

```
index=prod-service service.count | where sum('error.count') > 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
index=prod-service "service.error" | timechart sum(error.count) AS "Count" | stats sum("Count") as "Total"
```

And then in the alert settings I had to choose *custom* as trigger condition instead of *Number of Results* and enter:

```
search Total > 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `stats` command to add up all of the counts before using `where` to filter them.

```
index=prod-service service.count earliest=-60m
| stats sum('error.count') as total_errors
| where total_errors > 10
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. The query doesn't really show me anything in that case (when I do a search with it).